# .htaccess prevent loop and repeat language code in URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have site support many languages, and I'm using **.htaccess** to set languages as subfolders, like this:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(en|ar|ru|es|fr|pt)/(.*)$  $2?lang=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

The problem is, I can repeat and loop the languages code many times in URL, and I need to prevent that:

This is worked:

> https://example.com/ru/main?i.....

also, this is worked

> https://example.com/ru/ru/ru/ru/main?i.....

also, this is worked

> https://example.com/ru/en/pt/ar/main?i.....

I need only to call the language code one time, not repeat, and prevent and user to do that in URL.

Thanks

Comment: Always same language or can vary? Maybe `^((en|ar|ru|es|fr|pt)/)\1+`would give you more than 1 of first language

Comment: @user3783243 , yes, for all, lets said like this  example.com/ru/pt/en/ it's working and the site will be translated to Russian,

Comment: Examples should all go to russian, first language is intended? Maybe `^(en|ar|ru|es|fr|pt)/(?:en|ar|ru|es|fr|pt/?)*` will achieve that

Comment: @user3783243 , no, example.com/ar/pt/en/  will go to Arabic language, first one take always the correct language, but I don't want the user to repeat

Comment: I applied your answer like this  ^(en|ar|ru|es|fr|pt)/(?:en|ar|ru|es|fr|pt/?)*/(.*)$  $2?lang=$1  and now became working only if repeated 2 times, i don't know if i made any mistake in code above

Comment: @user3783243 can you please edit the above code that you set? It's worked but only if two times repeated, /ar/ru or /ru/ru,  also, now if we call only one not working

Comment: You mean `/ru/ru/ru` is not matched? Oh, the `/?` needs to be outside of language list, `^(en|ar|ru|es|fr|pt)/(?:(?:en|ar|ru|es|fr|pt)/?)*` might be what you want.

Comment: @user3783243 it's still not working, for the last code it's not allowed one in URL like /en/ , not it's need more than one to work like /en/en/ar/ .... but I think we are very close to solve it, that's what i set in my .htaccess  RewriteRule ^(en|ar|ru|es|fr|pt)/(?:(?:en|ar|ru|es|fr|pt)/?)*/(.*)$  $2?lang=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: Not clear what is being asked

Comment: @user3783243 .... The site have multi languages, and I can access to them by example.com/ru/file... or example.com/ar/file, and the site in this status can be translated normally, but if I go to URL bar and edit and increase the languages or repeat them, the site it will be translated but with a lot of languages code above,  not take to 404 page, example.com/ru/ru/ru/file or example.com/ar/en/ru/file
so will not be good if any user do that or for Google index in future